# How do I programatically access a spinner located inside the header of the NavigationView from the design support library?

Tags: android, android-spinner, androiddesignsupport

I am using the new design support library. For the navigation view you can specify a header. What I'm trying to do is **programatically access a spinner**, which is located inside the nav_header xml.

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner); // Normal initialization of a spinner
```

Located in activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header" <-- declaring nav_header as header layout
        app:itemIconTint="@color/primary_text"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/primary_text"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_draw_items" />
```

nav_header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/filter_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#2364AA"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:navigationContentDescription="@string/abc_action_bar_up_description"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/spinner_ll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/spinner_front"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Sort By: "
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner"           <-- what I'm trying to access
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:-

```
//Your navigation view
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_left);

//Now get the Spinner from the navigationView
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) navigationView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I decided to do away with the spinner and replace it with radio buttons. I also removed the header entirely. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps you, but my solution to get all the views from the Header's navigation view was to create a custom view based on Google's Navigation View that intercepts the methods which set the header's view and binds the databinding based on its view, so the custom class is something like that:

```
/**
 * Created by pokawa on 25/10/15.
 */
public class CustomNavigationView extends NavigationView {
    private static final String EXCEPTION_TAG_NULL_HEADER = "CustomNavigationView";
    private static final String EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_NULL_HEADER = "You have to set a header first";

    private View header;

    public CustomNavigationView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomNavigationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomNavigationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    /**
     * Overridden to store the header's view
     *
     * @param res header view id
     * @return header's view
     */
    @Override
    public View inflateHeaderView(int res) {
        header = super.inflateHeaderView(res);
        return header;
    }

    /**
     * Overridden to store the header's view
     *
     * @param view header
     */
    @Override
    public void addHeaderView(View view) {
        this.header = view;
        super.addHeaderView(view);
    }

    /**
     * Method used to retrieve header's data binding
     *
     * @return Header's view binding
     */
    public ViewDataBinding getHeaderDataBinding() {
        try{
            return DataBindingUtil.bind(header);
        } catch (NullPointerException exception) {
            Log.i(EXCEPTION_TAG_NULL_HEADER, EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_NULL_HEADER);
            throw exception;
        }
    }
}
```

And the XML to will be something like that:

```
<your.package.path.CustomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header" <-- declaring nav_header as header layout
        app:itemIconTint="@color/primary_text"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/primary_text"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_draw_items" />
```

Finally, an example how to retrieve the databinding:

```
    public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

        (...)
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            (...)
            YourLayoutBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.your_layout);
            NavHeaderBinding headerBinding = ((NavHeaderBinding) binding.navigationLeft.getHeaderDataBinding());
            Spinner spinner = headerBinding.spinnerLl;
            (...)
        }

        (...)
    }
```

PS: Of course I'm assuming that you're using new Google's feature (DataBinding), let me know if you're using another approach to inject view (e.g. ButterKnife) and I could help you with this.

See ya.

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of the design support library you can simply use the getHeaderView method, e.g.

```
View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView loginName = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.loginName);
loginName.setText(mApiHelper.getName());
```